# el JavaScript No ejecuta la funcion de input tipo file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

tengo un error que no he podido encontrar como solucionarlo.

tengo un input con una clase y un js y un css especial `iborrainputfile` que hace que el input se vea agradable.

El problema es que cuando lo cargo desde el html funciona perfectamente, pero cuando lo genero atraves de js no funciona (esto, por que no se cuantas imagenes quiera subir el usuario), ya hice las pruebas y creo el segundo elemento bien con su nombre y su id perfectamente, pero no me sube la imgen al label.

```js
/////////////////// Creo que el error pueda provenir de esta funcion, pero su sintaxis es desconocida para mi y no se como solucionarlo ////////////////////////

'use strict';

;( function ( document, window, index )
{
 var inputs = document.querySelectorAll( '.inputfile' );
 Array.prototype.forEach.call( inputs, function( input )
 {
  var label  = input.nextElementSibling,
   labelVal = label.innerHTML;

  input.addEventListener( 'change', function( e )
  {
   var fileName = '';
   if( this.files && this.files.length > 1 )
    fileName = ( this.getAttribute( 'data-multiple-caption' ) || '' ).replace( '{count}', this.files.length );
   else
    fileName = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();

   if( fileName )
    label.querySelector( 'span' ).innerHTML = fileName;
   else
    label.innerHTML = labelVal;
  });
 });
}( document, window, 0 ));


var contTitulo=0;
var numeroObs=0;
var numeroFoto=0;


function crearFoto() {
    var nuevaFoto="";
    nuevaFoto +="<div class='col-md-6' style='margin-bottom: 10px;''>";
    nuevaFoto +="<div class='conten'>";
    nuevaFoto +=   "<input style='text-align: center;' type='text' name='pieFoto_["+(contTitulo)+"]["+(numeroObs)+"]["+(numeroFoto+1)+"]' class='form-control' placeholder='Ingrese Pie-Foto'>";
    nuevaFoto +=    "<input type='file' name='file_["+(contTitulo)+"]["+(numeroObs)+"]["+(numeroFoto+1)+"]' id='file_"+(contTitulo)+""+(numeroObs)+""+(numeroFoto+1)+"' class='inputfile inputfile-7'>";
    nuevaFoto +=    "<label for='file_"+(contTitulo)+""+(numeroObs)+""+(numeroFoto+1)+"'>";
    nuevaFoto +=    "<span class='iborrainputfile'>Ninguna Seleccion</span>";
    nuevaFoto +=    "<strong>";
    nuevaFoto +=    "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' class='iborrainputfile' width='20' height='17' viewBox='0 0 20 17'><path d='M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z'></path></svg>";
    nuevaFoto +=    "Seleccione Foto</strong>";
    nuevaFoto +=    "</label>";
    nuevaFoto +="</div>";
    nuevaFoto +="</div>";

    $('#divObs_'+contTitulo+''+numeroObs).append(nuevaFoto);
    numeroFoto = numeroFoto +1;
}
```

```css
/**********File Inputs**********/
.inputfile {
    width: 0.1px;
    height: 0.1px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

.inputfile + label {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0.625rem 1.25rem;
}

.inputfile + label svg {
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    fill: currentColor;
    margin-top: -0.25em;
    margin-right: 0.25em;
}

.JJinputfile {
 font-size:16px; 
 font-weight:normal;
 font-family: 'Lato';
}


/* style 7 */

.inputfile-7 + label {
    color: #ec9b1b;
}

.inputfile-7 + label {
    border: 1px solid #ec9b1b;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
}

.inputfile-7:focus + label,
.inputfile-7.has-focus + label,
.inputfile-7 + label:hover {
    border-color: #d47e03;
}

.inputfile-7 + label span,
.inputfile-7 + label strong {
    padding: 0.625rem 1.25rem;
}

.inputfile-7 + label span {
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.inputfile-7 + label strong {
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ec9b1b;
    display: inline-block;
}

.inputfile-7:focus + label strong,
.inputfile-7.has-focus + label strong,
.inputfile-7 + label:hover strong {
    background-color: #d47e03;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 50em) {
 .inputfile-7 + label strong {
  display: block;
 }
}
.conten{
    border: 2px solid #ec9b1b;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;

}
/**********End File Inputs**********/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="titulos_0" class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 15px; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px ;">
<!-- contenedor de los titulos -->
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <label for="titulo_0" class="col-md-9 control-label" >Agregue un titulo</label>
      <label id="masContenido_0"  for="titulo" class="col-md-3 control-label masContenido_0" >Agregue Contenido</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input type="text" id="titulo_0" name="titulo_[0]" class="col-md-10 form-control ">
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- espacio para las fots -->
  <div id="divObs_00" class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 10px;">
      
    <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" >
      <div class="conten">
        <input style="text-align: center;" type="text" name="pieFoto_[0][0][0]" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Pie-Foto">

        <input type="file" name="file_[0][0][0]" id="file_000" class="inputfile inputfile-7">
        <label for="file_000">
        <span class="iborrainputfile">Ninguna Seleccion</span>
        <strong>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="iborrainputfile" width="20" height="17" viewBox="0 0 20 17"><path d="M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z"></path></svg>Seleccione Foto</strong>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
       
  </div>
  <div id="masFotos_00" style="text-align: right; margin-right: 15px; ">
    <label class="control-label">Agregar mas Fotos</label>
    <button id="masFotos_00"  type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="crearFoto()"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></button>
  </div>
<!-- Observvaciones -->
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="observaciones_00" class="col-md-12 control-label" >Observaciones</label>
    <input type="text" name="observaciones_[0][0]" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

El problema creo que radica en la funcion de js que no se como hacer para se active cuando se se crea el nuevo input mediante js...

Espero haber sido claro y que me puedan colaborar....

Answer (score 0):

El problema es el momento en que asignas el manejador del evento `change`.  Cuando inicia tu página, recorre todos los `<input>` y les asigna la función que se va a disparar cuando cambien, el problema es que cualquier `<input>` que se agregue al HTML luego de esto no tendrá esa función.

Una forma sería agregarle la función a penas agregues el elemento a la página, pero te ofrezco una alternativa mejor, manejarlo con un solo evento.  En lugar de agregar una función por cada elemento puedes utilizar un contenedor para todos los `<input>` y este sería el que tendría la función, entonces cualquier cambio que ocurra dentro del contenedor será manejado.  Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var contenedor = $('#contenedor');

$('#btn-agregar').click(function() {
  contenedor.append('<input />');
});

contenedor.on('change', 'input' /* selector */, function(e) {
  // Debido al selector en el segundo parámetro
  // solo se manejarán los eventos disparados por <input>
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenedor">
  <input />
</div>
<button id="btn-agregar">agregar</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda caballero, realmente no me funciono de la forma que mencionaste, no habia respondido por que me quede sin acceso a la cuenta jejejeje, igual ya losolucione de otra forma